# angular ui-router and view context update

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

i'm new to ui-router;

Say i have a "pageTitle" ui-view with template like `<p>{{ count }} results</p>` in my AngularJS ui-router application.

How would a controller update this view context asynchronously ? For example after a search request, i'd like to update the count in the bar.

Should i use classic service+scope variable or is there something better integrated in ui-router ?

I was thinking about something like `uiView.get('breadcrumb').updateData({count: 42})` but maybe its silly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should only use ui-router for routing, which means you can use it to map a url to a controller and optionally use `resolve` to request data from the service before the controller/template are rendered.

Once that is done ui-router is out of the picture for the most part, and if you need to update something on the page or make additional http calls, you just do it the same way you'd do in a normal controller. The only thing you would go back to ui-router for would be to transition to a new state, so unless the count of your results is a different state (with a different url) then ui-router should not be involved in the picture.